# No module named 'tweepy'

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a Twitter bot but when I install the tweepy package it gives me the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'

I've tried uninstalling and installing tweepy and it still doesn't work. i'm running python 3.9.2

Comment: are installing it using what? and how?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: just type pip install tweepy in to the terminal next to the console